# Use Objective-C class in Swift show variable as <<error type>>. Code compile fine

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am writing my new ViewControllers in Swift inside existing Obj-C project.  Got stuck on this `<<error type>>` issue:

1. My Objective-C classes in my Swift code are shown as `<<error type>>`, instead of the proper class name.
2. I don't get code auto-complete for Objective-C class method and variables.  I noticed this happens when the variable type is `<<error type>>`

If I spell out exact class name and class method name they all compile fine and run without error.

Here are my class declarations:

```
//  Localizer.h
//  This is the Objective-C class
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Localizer : NSObject {
}

+(Localizer*)sharedInstance;
+(NSString *)getLocalizedText:(NSString *)localConstant;
@end
```

Here is the .m file:

```
//
//  Localizer.m
//

#import "Localizer.h"

static Localizer *sharedInstance;

@interface Localizer ()

@end

@implementation Localizer

+(Localizer*)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[Localizer alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

-(Localizer*)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        //some logic after init     
    }
    return self;
}

+(NSString *)getLocalizedText:(NSString *)localConstant
{
    NSString *foundVal = @“translated text”;

    return foundVal;
}

@end
```

This is my bridge header file:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "Localizer.h"
```

Here are how I use Localizer in .swift class, **(edited)with more detail**:

```
@IBAction func btnNextPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let companyCodeStr = self.txtFldCompanyCode.text

    if companyCodeIsSane(companyCodeStr)
    {
        if let authController = Core.sharedInstance().authController
        {
            authController.lookupWithCompanyCode(companyCodeStr, completion: { (queryResult: CorpQuery!, coreResponse: CoreResponse!) -> Void in

                if (coreResponse.error == nil)
                {
                        // company disabled
                        if !queryResult.enabled && queryResult.status == "OK"
                        {
                            let alertTitle = ""
                            let alertMessage = Localizer.getLocalizedText("COMPANY_DISABLED_MSG")
                            let alertCancelText = Localizer.getLocalizedText("LABEL_OK_BTN");

                            let alertView = UIAlertView(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: alertCancelText)
                            alertView.show()
                        }
                        // Invalid company code
                        else if queryResult.status == "FAIL"
                        {
                            let alertTitle: String = Localizer.getLocalizedText("Wrong company code")
                            let alertMessage = Localizer.getLocalizedText("ERROR_INVALID_COMPANY_CODE")
                            let alertCancelText = Localizer.getLocalizedText("LABEL_CLOSE_BTN");

                            let alertView = UIAlertView(title: alertTitle, message: alertMessage, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: alertCancelText)
                            alertView.show()
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    println("company code lookup failure \(coreResponse.error)")
                }
            })
        }
    }



}
```

While typing out "alert", Xcode automatically shows hit:
[image: Xcode auto complete hint]

But they all shown variable type as `<<error type>>`, instead of String, or UIAlertView.  I believe the problem is with how I am using the Objective-C class "Localizer.h".

If I type `let translator = Localizer.sharedInstance()` or `Local`, I do not get correct auto complete code hit:
[image: auto complete for 'alert']

When typing "local.." I get:[image: auto complete for "local"]

I do not get "Localizer" as one of the option in the choices.

If I type out `let alertTitle: String = Localizer.getLocalizedText("translate me")`, I will get correct object type the next time I type `alertTitle`.
Type shown as String:
[image: shown correct type]

It seems like Xcode or Swift complier doesn't know Localizer class method returns a String.

I am using Xcode 6.4 and I tried deleting /DerivedData folder and "com.apple.dt.Xcode" file. Also tried all kinds of Clean and rebuild" project.
Experiment with Optional binding/chaining a bit.

None of my efforts give me the correct object type and auto code complete.

Comment: I believe it is related to your context of these code. I tested it and it seems work well for me in a plain method. May I know where did you put your code? Is it in a closure or something special else? It would be a help if you can paste the context you are using it.

Comment: @onevcat.  You are spot on!  It is in a closure.  I am editing my original post.  Thanks.

Comment: That's just type inference screwing up, I get that all the time ;) the compiler needs time to evolve 

Comment: @HAS, okay.  We just need to live with this for right now?  Not much we can do?

Comment: @Codefreeeeeeeze Unfortunately not ... But you can always file radars :)

Comment: @Codefreeeeeeeeze I somehow forgot to mention that you could try to explicitly set the type like so: `let localizer: Localizer = Localizer().sharedInstance`. Maybe that helps ;)

Comment: @HAS.  Thanks for that suggestion.  Tried with no success.  Still shows `<<error type>>`. `let translator: Localizer = Localizer.sharedInstance()`.  translator shown as `<<error type>>`

Comment: :/ Maybe cmd+b? In any case if you have the time to localize the issue (is it because it is an objc bridged class? Or is it because it's in a closure (that might explain why `alertView` etc. don't get recognized)? Maybe you can try it on the latest Xcode 7 Beta) and file a bug report at [bugreport.apple.com](bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: @HAS.  Even things are in a closure.  If I write `let alertTitle = "alert"`, without using my Obj-C Localizer class.  alertTitle shows correct type as `String`.  I really think the problem is with those Obj-C class `#import` via the bridge header.  Maybe problem with the way I use it, maybe bug in Xcode 7.  I will fill bug against Apple when I get a chance.

Comment: @Codefreeeeeeeze Great! If they don't know a bug they cannot eliminate it :)

Comment: Good n' bad news.  My Xcode code auto-complete not happening issue and `<<error type>>` magically disappeared.  (That's the good news).  Bad news is that I am not sure what exactly is the remedy.  I will try to find it out, only thing I did is setup unit test for my new swift class.  While setting up the unit test, I had to checkbox my .swift code(test target code) in both app & test target.  My .swift XCTest class is only checked in test target.  This triggered all kinds of rebuild and generated a bridge header file for test target.  After that all the problem is gone...

Comment: @Codefreeeeeeeze That's indeed strange ...